# Convert event without EventArgs using Observable.FromEvent

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive

I'm struggling with converting the following event to an `IObservable`:

```
public delegate void _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler();
event _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler Opened;
```

The event comes from a library so I can't change it.
The overload of `IObservable.FromEvent` that should do it has the following signature:

```
public static IObservable<Unit> FromEvent
    ( Action<Action> addHandler
    , Action<Action> removeHandler
    )
```

So I tried converting the event like this:

```
var opened = Observable.FromEvent
    ( h => _SolutionEvents.Opened += h
    , h => _SolutionEvents.Opened -= h
    );
```

But the compiler doesn't like `_SolutionEvents.Opened += h` and `_SolutionEvents.Opened += h` because

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action' to 'EnvDTE._dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler'.

I don't think that I can just say`_SolutionEvents.Opened += new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(h)` because then removal won't work because I have a different instance, right?

There is another overload of `Observable.FromEvent` with the following signature:

```
public static IObservable<TEventArgs> FromEvent<TDelegate, TEventArgs>
    ( Func<Action<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion
    , Action<TDelegate> addHandler
    , Action<TDelegate> removeHandler
    )
```

This one allows to convert the action to an event handler, but it seems to only work with `TEventArgs`.

Is Rx missing an appropriate overload or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This turns out that it is very easy to use the `FromEvent` pattern.

Just do this:

```
var opened = Observable.FromEvent<_dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler, Unit>(
    h => () => h(Unit.Default),
    h => _SolutionEvents.Opened += h,
    h => _SolutionEvents.Opened -= h);
```

I've tested the observable with this code:

```
void Main()
{
    var _SolutionEvents = new Foo();

    var opened = Observable.FromEvent<_dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler, Unit>(h => () => h(Unit.Default), h => _SolutionEvents.Opened += h, h => _SolutionEvents.Opened -= h);

    opened.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Opened"));

    _SolutionEvents.OnOpened();
}

public delegate void _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler();

public class Foo
{
    public event _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler Opened;

    public void OnOpened()
    {
        this.Opened?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

It produces the following expected output:

```
Opened
```

It's worth noting that there is no `IObservable` interface, but only an `IObservable<T>` so you must return something. The trick here is to convert `delegate void _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler()` into an `IObservable<Unit>` to make it work and that's what the `h => () => h(Unit.Default)` does.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks. And it should also correctly remove the event handler when you dispose the subscription.

Comment: @JohannesEgger - Yes, it will correctly remove the handler when **either** the subscription is disposed **or** the observable naturally ends. So, for example, if you added a `.Take(1)` to the observable then it will remove handler immediately after one value is produced.

Comment: Just a clarification on the disposal; the subscription will be disposed when the the observable sequence naturally ends, that is why it will correctly remove the event handler. i.e when a sequence terminates (OnError/OnComplete) any subscriptions are disposed. Independently, the disposal semantics will remove the handler.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - What do you mean by "Independently, the disposal semantics will remove the handler."? Do you mean by either explicit disposal or natural end?

Answer (score 5):

You are running into a a type issue here. The `_dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler` type is not `Action`. It looks like the `Action` type, but it is not the `Action` type.

IMO this event does not conform to the .NET standards for events. Generally the delegate would match the pattern of taking a sender `object` parameter and an `EventArg` subclass of for the second parameter.

ie.

```
public delegate void _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

If you try to just attach an `Action` to the event you will find that fails too.

```
Action onOpened = ()=>Console.WriteLine("Opened");
_SolutionEvents.Opened += onOpened;  //CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action' to '_dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler'
```

The compiler is smart enough to do some type inference if you do this;

```
_SolutionEvents.Opened+= () => Console.WriteLine("Opened");
```

but when you are using Rx, you are already typed into the `Action` type, so are effectively back at the previous issue above.

If the library owner was nice, the event would follow the normal sender/eventArgs pattern. Failing that, they would at least specify the delegate as just an `Action` instead of their own customer parameterless, void method. :-/

So, as the event you have doesn't meet the standard .NET patterns, you will need to provide Rx some more hand-holding (blame your library provider not Rx).

You could fight the `FromEvent`/`FromEventPattern` methods, but as your library is not in the spirit of an Event, I would suggest just going with the simple use of `Observable.Create` which at least keeps the code obvious what is happening and should allow the next user to better understand it.

```
Observable.Create<Unit>(obs =>
{
    _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler handler = () => obs.OnNext(Unit.Default);

    _SolutionEvents.Opened += handler;
    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Create(() => _SolutionEvents.Opened -= handler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Anyway Rx seems to be able to handle non-standard events (with `FromEvent`) so I thought it should work with _any_ non-standard event. So I guess @Enigmativity's answer is the one that's in the Rx spirit. But yours is also a neat solution, thanks.

Comment: Yes, his is an excellent answer (upvote). If you have a concern about garbage/allocations, then reconsider using the `FromEventXXX` methods as they can be unnecessarily allocation heavy - see https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Model/PropertyChange.md

Comment: That's quite interesting. Thanks for that.