# Parameter less delegate in Reactive Extensions in a Universal C# Windows App

Tags: c#, system.reactive, windows-10-universal

I have an eventhanler:

```
 public delegate void OnSizeEventHandler();
```

And I have the class that triggers the event of that type

```
CustomObject.OnSize += OnResize;
```

As you can see it's just a parameterless delegate.

I want to use it from reactive extensions like:

```
    var eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent<OnSizeEventHandler>(           
       x => CustomObject.OnSize += x,
       x => CustomObject.OnSize -= x);
```

I get this error:

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action<CustomObject.OnSizeEventHandler>' to 'CustomObject.OnSizeEventHandler'
```

What am I doing wrong? It works pretty fine with EventHandlers but when it comes to a custom event, it's so hard to figure out how to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, it's quite tricky just to map to a parameterless event but it works:

[Convert event without EventArgs using Observable.FromEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860449/convert-event-without-eventargs-using-observable-fromevent/35861252)

```
var opened = Observable.FromEvent<_dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler, Unit>(
h => () => h(Unit.Default),
h => _SolutionEvents.Opened += h,
h => _SolutionEvents.Opened -= h);
```

I'd likw RX to be more simple or to include an overload of the FromEvent if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the overloads of [`FromEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromevent(v=vs.103).aspx), you'll see there aren't any that match your current call.

You might want to try using this instead:

```
var eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent<OnSizeEventHandler>(           
   (Action x) => CustomObject.OnSize += new OnSizeEventHandler(x),
   (Action x) => CustomObject.OnSize -= new OnSizeEventHandler(x));
```

Basically, that's attempting to take the Rx support for `Action`-based events, and wrap the action that's passed in an `OnSizeEventHandler` each time.

I wouldn't like to guarantee that it'll work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the answer, I use that convention whenever I can but this delegate is from a library I cannot modify. The answer you suggest, although it compiles it throws an exception:  Additional information: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type. It is expecting a delegate with a parameter and my delegate is parameterless.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda: It would have been useful to state that the delegate is out of your control within the question. Shame about the exception - will edit.